# I got a rock stuck in my charging port for my iPhone and my charger won’t go into the hole I need ways to get it out please?

Tags: iphone, charging, charger

Rock stuck in charging port from park is st the end of the port and I don’t know how to get it out

Comment: Hi! could you post a photo ? use [edit] button and the picture icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get it out with fine tipped tweezers, you can try a tooth pick and super glue.  Put a tiny amount on the tip of the toothpick.  Then touch the tip of it to the stone, and hold it there until it sets.  Then pull it out.  I don't recommend this if you can't insert the toothpick without touching the inside walls of the charging port, though.